# Editing/extracting a Column expression in google refine / OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine

i'm using Google Refine v2.5.  I created a column that uses some complex logic to fetch info from a url, but I realized I need to tweak it.  Is there any way for me to edit or extract the expression I used?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All expressions used for facets, transformations, and column additions are kept in the history that you can access by clicking on the history tab in the preview dialog.

Comment: ah! Excellent. Thank you.  For anyone else reading this, that the little number next to the Undo/Redo option in the upper left corner

Comment: Actually that's not the history I was talking about.  When you click "Add cell by fetching URL" (or Edit cell->Transform or custom facets), the expression dialog that comes up has a tab labeled "History" which has copies of all the recent expressions used.  You can click "Reuse" next to one and then use it again or modify it and use it.